# what library shall i use to send email by ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, email-client

Now i want to write one app which send emails millions each day by ruby, now i know there is some options such as net::smtp and actionmailer, maybe others, could someone recommend one better library so that i can use it to finish my task.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using the [mail](https://rubygems.org/gems/mail) gem. ActionMailer in rails 3 uses it under the hood and it works with 1.9.2 and jruby and there is loads of good documentation here: https://github.com/mikel/mail

Code example:

```
Mail.deliver do
   from     'me@test.lindsaar.net'
   to       'you@test.lindsaar.net'
   subject  'Here is the image you wanted'
   body     File.read('body.txt')
   add_file '/full/path/to/somefile.png'
end
```

Something else you might want to consider is using [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com/) or [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) to send email for you, they have all of the infrastructure already in place and ensure excellent deliverability.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it.

Using smtp : [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_sending_email.htm)

If you are using Rails : [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-send-email.htm)

If you want to use gems : [pony](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pony/1.2/frames)

Comment: Must be smtp since the other two use smtp anyway.

Comment: @Themasterhimself thanks, could you give me some performance suggestions on smtp, rails and pony even though rails and pony uses smtp? thank u.

Comment: which is better on performance for sending emails? that's my meaning.

Comment: Use smtp directly if you want to optimize on performance..just follow the first link.